# Calculating perplexity for LSA

Tags: machine-learning, topic-models, latent-semantic-indexing

I am new to topic modelling, so kindly bear me if my question is silly.

I am trying to calculate perplexity after applying LSA. i am aware that LSA returns negative values, so i followed the steps stated in [coccaro](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.54.508&rep=rep1&type=pdf) to find the propability of each word in the vocabulary(which i am still not clear whether must i calculate for the whole vocabulary or word by word in the given test document).

Now how do i calculate perplexity?

How must i find the document propability ? must i find the sum of propabilities of  individual words in the document and call it as document propability. what if the words are repeated.

**update**

I found the following stackoverflow [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10302/what-is-perplexity) which talks about PLSA.From that , perplexity is given as
2^−∑(i=1 to N)(1/N)log2q(xi)

How can i estimate log q(xi) in that equation for LSA.